# Merge two keyboard layouts into one

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I'm a Dvorak user but I also need to use international keyboard too. The problem is - when I use international phonetic keyboard it's based on Qwerty.

When I have hardware support for Dvorak (on typematrix keyboard) it all works perfectly, but when I'm on my laptop, I can't use combinations of two layouts.

How can I create a custom layout which would be a combination of two keyboard layouts? If there is no way, please suggest some tool to create a custom keyboard layout for a Mac OSX.

I'm on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

What IPA layout do you use? [SIL's website](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=ipa-sil_keyboard) has one for Dvorak. You could edit other keyboard layouts with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) or directly as XML.

You could also try adding something like this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document-private-xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook.

```
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<inputmode_not>ROMAN</inputmode_not>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Q, KeyCode::QUOTE</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::W, KeyCode::COMMA</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::E, KeyCode::DOT</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::R, KeyCode::P</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::T, KeyCode::Y</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Y, KeyCode::F</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::U, KeyCode::G</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::I, KeyCode::C</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::O, KeyCode::R</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::P, KeyCode::L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, KeyCode::SLASH</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, KeyCode::EQUAL</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::S, KeyCode::O</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::D, KeyCode::E</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F, KeyCode::U</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::G, KeyCode::I</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::H, KeyCode::D</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::J, KeyCode::H</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::K, KeyCode::T</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::L, KeyCode::N</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SEMICOLON, KeyCode::S</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::QUOTE, KeyCode::MINUS</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Z, KeyCode::SEMICOLON</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::X, KeyCode::Q</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::C, KeyCode::J</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::V, KeyCode::K</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::B, KeyCode::X</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::N, KeyCode::B</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::COMMA, KeyCode::W</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::DOT, KeyCode::V</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SLASH, KeyCode::Z</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::MINUS, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::EQUAL, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT</autogen>
</item>
```

It's based on `remap.qwerty2dvorak` in the [checkbox.xml in the test folder](https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

If someone else was looking for a way to change the input method when holding a key, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/toggle-the-keyboard-language-by-holding-a-button).